# Which is the fastest way to replace all "underscores _" in filenames with "space"

Tags: windows-7, filenames, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

I have many PDFs of EBooks but some of them have `underscores` in their filenames so it becomes difficult to search the file by some words. Is there any program/script/software which replace all  underscores with blank space in windows 7

Comment: Definitely a dupe.

Comment: Duplicate post [(link)](http://superuser.com/questions/65966/batch-file-to-replace-a-single-character-in-windows-filenames/65995?noredirect=1#comment772523_65995). 

Here's your one-liner CLI answer - without installing additional software:

`for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('dir /b "*.pdf"') do Set LIST=%i& set LIST | ren "%~fi" "%LIST:_= %"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really old software, but I use [Lupas Rename 2000](http://rename.lupasfreeware.org/) to rename files in bulk. One of the rules you can use is "Replace text (_) with new text ( )".

It was last updated in 2005, but it is light, fast, and still works in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
dir *.pdf /b | mawk "/ / { q=sprintf('%c',34); new=$0; gsub(/ /, '_', new ); print     'ren 'q$0q' 'new }"
```

This command will not do anything, but output the command *about* to be executed.  To execute it, you just add cmd at the end:

```
dir *.pdf  /b  |  mawk  "/ / { q=sprintf('%c',34); new=$0; gsub(/ /, '_', new ); print 'ren 'q$0q' 'new }" | cmd
```

You can download mawk.exe from http://www.klabaster.com/freeware.htm#mawk